# When multiple calls to the same UDF are in a single statement, how many times will it be called?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the following t-sql statement, how many times will the dbo.FUNC function get called?

```
SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    dbo.FUNC(column3) AS column3
FROM table1
WHERE dbo.FUNC(column3) >= 5
ORDER BY dbo.FUNC(column3) DESC
```

Will it called multiple separate times per row, or does the optimizer recognize that it is being used multiple times in a single statement, and only call it once?

How can I test this?  I can't insert into a table inside of a function, so incrementing a counter wont work...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't guaranteed.

You would need to check the execution plan to find out. Some examples.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FUNC1(@p1 int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @p1 + 1
END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FUNC2(@p1 int)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @p1 + 1
END

GO
SELECT 
       OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID('dbo.FUNC1'), 'IsDeterministic'),
       OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID('dbo.FUNC2'), 'IsDeterministic') 
GO
```

`FUNC2` is created `WITH SCHEMABINDING` and is treated as deterministic. `FUNC1` isn't.

```
SELECT
    dbo.FUNC1(number) AS FUNC1,
    dbo.FUNC2(number) AS FUNC2
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE dbo.FUNC1(number) >= 5 AND dbo.FUNC2(number) >= 5
ORDER BY dbo.FUNC1(number), dbo.FUNC2(number)
```

Gives Plan

[image: PLAN1]

```
  |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Expr1003] ASC, [Expr1004] ASC))
       |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=[test].[dbo].[FUNC1]([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[number])))
            |--Filter(WHERE:([test].[dbo].[FUNC1]([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[number])>=(5) AND [Expr1004]>=(5)))
                 |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=[test].[dbo].[FUNC2]([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[number])))
                      |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[ix2_spt_values_nu_nc]))
```

`FUNC1` is evaluated twice (once in the filter and once in a compute scalar outputting a calculated column used for both the projection and the ordering), `FUNC2` is only evaluated once.

Rewriting as

```
SELECT
    FUNC1,
    FUNC2
FROM master..spt_values
CROSS APPLY (SELECT dbo.FUNC1(number), dbo.FUNC2(number)) C(FUNC1, FUNC2)
WHERE FUNC1 >= 5 AND FUNC2 >= 5
ORDER BY FUNC1, FUNC2
```

Changes the plan slightly and both are only evaluated once

[image: Plan 2]

```
  |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Expr1003] ASC, [Expr1004] ASC))
       |--Filter(WHERE:([Expr1003]>=(5)))
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=[test].[dbo].[FUNC1]([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[number])))
                 |--Filter(WHERE:([Expr1004]>=(5)))
                      |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=[test].[dbo].[FUNC2]([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[number])))
                           |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[ix2_spt_values_nu_nc]))
```

Now making a slight alteration to the query

```
SELECT
    FUNC1 + 10,
    FUNC2 + 10
FROM master..spt_values
CROSS APPLY (SELECT dbo.FUNC1(number), dbo.FUNC2(number)) C(FUNC1, FUNC2)
WHERE FUNC1 >= 5 AND FUNC2 >= 5
ORDER BY FUNC1, FUNC2
```

Gives the opposite of the original result in that `FUNC2` is evaluated twice but `FUNC1` only once.

[image: Plan 3]

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1005]=[Expr1003]+(10)))
       |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Expr1003] ASC, [Expr1004] ASC))
            |--Filter(WHERE:([Expr1003]>=(5)))
                 |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=[test].[dbo].[FUNC1]([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[number])))
                      |--Filter(WHERE:([Expr1004]>=(5)))
                           |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=[test].[dbo].[FUNC2]([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[number]), [Expr1006]=[test].[dbo].[FUNC2]([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[number])+(10)))
                                |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([master].[dbo].[spt_values].[ix2_spt_values_nu_nc]))
```

Comment: How do you know it got called twice?

Comment: The plan shows it is called once in the Filter expression, then the next operator along is a compute scalar that calls the function again, outputs the result as a column `Expr1003` and that column is used both for the select and the order by.

Comment: +good example. I'd assume that non-in-line-table UDF is *always* evaluated once per row per mention unless there is an obvious shortcut (eg ORDER BY expression exactly matches SELECT expression)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it depends on if the function is deterministic.

Even then, that will only be used for multiple calls on a single row.

I believe your case would be optimized if the function is deterministic.

Comment: my function is deterministic, although I was hoping for an "I know for sure" answer, and not an "I believe" answer.

Comment: @GabrielMcAdams When it comes to the optimizer, you can't guarantee anything - it's allowed to do whatever it wants as long as it preserves the semantics.  This is particularly problematic with scalar UDFs.  In general, avoid scalar UDFs called over large data sets or ensure they are only called once by using CTEs or temporary tables to ensure logical order of operations.  In fact, it is sometimes far more efficient to turn a UDF into a pre-calculated lookup table even over a fairly large multi-dimansional domain.

Comment: +1 Supporting this answer if I create the function `WITH SCHEMABINDING` it then moves the compute scalar before the filter in the first query in my answer.

Comment: But even with the schemabinding option if I try `ORDER BY dbo.FUNC(number)+5` I see two calls per row rather than just one.

Comment: When I add `WITH SCHEMABINDING`, I only see it being called once (Compute Scalar - Filter and Sort are using the expression that was created during Compute Scalar)

Comment: @GabrielMcAdams - Yep, That's what I see too. I thought it was implied from my comment.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I mean that even with the order by that you added, I only see it called once.

Comment: @GabrielMcAdams - Ah OK. For me that one varies actually as per my extended answer.

Answer (score -2):

yes.

the optimizer has the sufficient knowledge to optimize this into a same calc while running.

you can look at the execution plan to see it.

Comment: The execution plan doesn't appear to be accurate when it comes to CLR functions, recursion, and loops, though.

Comment: does FUNc is clr enable func ?

Comment: in my case, FUNC is a CLR UDF

Comment: @great so in the clr dll you can write to logEvent `EventLog.WriteEntry...`

Comment: ok.  That's a good way to test it. Can you think of a way that is more isolated then the event log?  I know you can't insert into a table, but is there something else I can do that'll put the counter somewhere by itself, easy to read?

Comment: @GabrielMcAdams if you truly want to use a counter  - write to a file or to a registry . ie your func clr will increase the reg entry by 1 each time. is that ok ?

Comment: Good ideas.  I'll test using a registry counter.

Comment: This is wrong: functions like this are almost always executed once per row. Only the ORDER BY will take the value from the SELECT