# Does SQL Server cache scalar function results when used simultaneously in SELECT, WHERE and GROUP BY?

Tags: sql-server

Consider this contrived example:

```
SELECT
    Foo,
    dbo.ExpensiveScalarFunction( Bar ),
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    Source
WHERE
    dbo.ExpensiveScalarFunction( Bar ) <> 'abc'
GROUP BY
    Foo,
    dbo.ExpensiveScalarFunction( Bar )
HAVING
    dbo.ExpensiveScalarFunction( Bar ) > 'abd'
```

Would `ExpensiveScalarFunction` be evaluated 4 times for each row, or only once? Is SQL Server able to identify that the function is deterministic and optimize for that case?

Comment: There is no guarantee. Read the answer here by @Martin Smith: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8964858/2203084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely echo the comment from @wewestthemeance that there are no guarantees, and the link is an excellent overview of why. The optimizer can choose and may not necessarily be consistent. Putting your example into executable code, my optimizer called the function twice - once in the filter/`WHERE` predicate, and then again for the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`, which makes sense since the filter is applied before the aggregation, and it does not repeat the function call in the `GROUP` and `SELECT`.

Sample code:

```
SELECT A, dbo.f_Double(A)
FROM (SELECT 2) T (A)
WHERE dbo.f_Double(A) > 0
GROUP BY A,dbo.f_Double(A)
```